How to make group policy in Active Directory to allow the certain user to change their regional settings?
I want to allow a specific set of users can change their regional settings (eg, date format, number format)

Tell us the steps that the users are taking when changing the regional settings, and what happens when they attempt the change.

@GregAskew when domain users try to change regional settings (eg, date format, number format) it return back to default setting as same as domain computer after few hours. I wants to allow only some specific users that they can change regional settings. So I should create one group policy (it can allow to change regional setting) and apply that gpo to those users.

That isn't normal. It means that there are other policies in effect changing the regional settings. What have you reviewed of the policies on the endpoints?

@GregAskew could you please tell me how to make policy to change regional settings by users? Currently I don't have any policy regarding regional settings.

There is a mechanism reverting any changes. That needs to be identified first. You should include how you are assessing that on the endpoints, that is the first and best source of information.
